# looping through different files existing in one folder

Tags: java

I have a java program that reads each line in a file text and processes the text of a file, then print the result. I need to do the same thing for each file exist in a specific folder (directory). So, I need the program to go through each file in the folder and extract the content of the text ..etc. my question is how can I loop through each file in a folder using Java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you created a `File` object that refers to the directory, you can call [`listFiles`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29) to get an array of all the files in the directory.

```
// assuming myDir is the File object that represents the directory
File[] dirContent = myDir.listFiles();
for (File f : dirContent)
{
    if (!f.isDirectory())
    {
        // process file.
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can get only the list of files that are not directories by calling [`File#listFiles(FileFilter)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28java.io.FileFilter%29) with an appropriate file filter. E.g.:

```
// assuming myDir is the File object that represents the directory
File[] dirContent = myDir.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
    @Override boolean accept(File pathname)
    {
        return !pathname.isDirectory();
    }
});
for (File f : dirContent)
{
    // process file.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just like to throw out another way to do this. This file search and process software: http://www.softpedia.com/get/File-managers/JFileProcessor.shtml https://github.com/stant/jfileprocessor

Will let you search for files with glob or regex, in subfolders to X or all depth, by name, size, date. You can save to a List window or file. Then you can run a groovy (think java) script to do whatever you want to the list of files; zip or tar them, modify the list strings like sed, delete, move, copy files, grep or ls -l them, whatever. It will also let you massage your list like add to, delete from, subtract one list from another.